# What's the best way to view changes that emerged due to upgrades of TeX Live?

Tags: fonts, texlive, revision-control

I have a two-column small-font LaTeX document (a long paper spread onto several source files). A PDF file was compiled from it using TeX Live (which was in stock Debian, stock Ubuntu, or locally installed) in January 2022:

```
$ pdfinfo main.pdf
Title:           …
Subject:         
Keywords:        
Author:          …
Creator:         LaTeX with hyperref
Producer:        pdfTeX-1.40.21
CreationDate:    Sat Jan  1 03:19:53 2022 CET
ModDate:         Sat Jan  1 03:19:53 2022 CET
Custom Metadata: yes
Metadata Stream: no
Tagged:          no
UserProperties:  no
Suspects:        no
Form:            none
JavaScript:      no
Pages:           31
Encrypted:       no
Page size:       595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
Page rot:        0
File size:       743054 bytes
Optimized:       no
PDF version:     1.5
```

Compiling the same sources today yields

```
$ pdfinfo main.pdf
Title:           …
Subject:         
Keywords:        
Author:          …
Creator:         LaTeX with hyperref
Producer:        pdfTeX-1.40.25
CreationDate:    Sat Dec  9 22:43:25 2023 CET
ModDate:         Sat Dec  9 22:43:25 2023 CET
Custom Metadata: yes
Metadata Stream: no
Tagged:          no
UserProperties:  no
Suspects:        no
Form:            none
JavaScript:      no
Pages:           31
Encrypted:       no
Page size:       595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
Page rot:        0
File size:       998103 bytes
Optimized:       no
PDF version:     1.5
```

Viewing the changes between the old main.pdf and the new main.pdf via `diffpdf` yields ***way too many*** red markings in any mode (word comparison, character comparison, visual comparison). So, at least with its default options, *diffpdf* is useless in this case: using it would boil down to manually examining all the text on the 2 × 31 pages side by side.  Though, upon the examination of the first lines of the first page (title, authors, and abstract), you find that the font smoothing/antialiasing is working now whereas it did not work (properly) earlier, and that the occurrences of the ligature ﬁ are now marked as different between the versions. You wish to understand whether there are more important changes beyond this (e.g., characters displayed improperly or differently, unexpected changes in how TikZ draws stuff now, any errors in references/citations, any hyphenation errors, …). Unfortunately, the old main.log is no longer available. The new main.log contains warnings about lots of stuff, including undefined and multiply-defined stuff, but, as you're using the package *xr-hyper* to produce your documents (main.pdf as the abriged version of the paper, and apart thereof you may produce from the same sources another PDF file for the supplemental material containing mathematical proofs, and you may also produce yet one more PDF file for everything together), at least some such warnings on undefined or multiply-defined labels are not completely unexpected.

Is there any way to “roughen” *diffpdf*, or is there any other tool that would compare the old main.pdf and the new main.pdf more coarsely than *diffpdf*?

I tried comparing the texts, but the amount of changes is huge:

```bash
$ diff -d <(pdftotext new_main.pdf -) <(pdftotext old_main.pdf -)|wc -l
12812
```

Comparing the fonts yields a bit more information:

```bash
$ diff -d <(pdffonts new_main.pdf) <(pdffonts old_main.pdf)
3,55c3,56
< KYESCI+SFRM1728                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     22  0
< YHWNWE+SFCC1200                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     23  0
< UFXXMG+SFCC0800                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     24  0
< TQJZEA+SFTI0700                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     25  0
< IXSXOZ+SFTI0900                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     26  0
< PIFFSP+SFBX0900                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     27  0
< ZPBWIJ+SFBX1000                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     30  0
< EYUFFD+SFCC1000                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     31  0
< UPNPHM+SFRM1000                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     32  0
< JIZZNP+SFTI1000                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     35  0
< XAOMZI+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes     36  0
< VSAEDQ+CMMI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes     69  0
< DITMCZ+CMSY10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes     70  0
< DIERKS+CMR7                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes     71  0
< CHUDXO+SFRM0700                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     73  0
< UPNPHM+SFRM1000                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     74  0
< ADNPKL+SFRM0600                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     75  0
< EHAKQD+SFRM0800                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     77  0
< KUUXAH+SFTT1000                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes    112  0
< RQSHZS+CMTT10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    226  0
< DSIQTY+BBOLD10                       Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    229  0
< ULAAHX+CMTI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    231  0
< OVETDW+CMMI7                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    232  0
< TGNRDB+SFRM0900                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes    243  0
< CYIPZU+MSAM10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    262  0
< PGWCIV+CMEX10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    264  0
< AWNQRZ+CMSY7                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    265  0
< OYQULM+EUFM10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    266  0
< UWDUBS+CMR5                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    267  0
< ZSIWIM+CMSS10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    268  0
< LUAFXG+rsfs10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    269  0
< HQDOIX+CMMI12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    279  0
< XLUXEV+CMR8                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    280  0
< CHYDRB+MSBM10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    301  0
< SFQIJW+CMSS9                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    303  0
< ECGVGR+CMR9                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    304  0
< BHDBNY+CMMI9                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    305  0
< JIXOQS+CMSY9                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    308  0
< ECVLCM+SFIT0900                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes    328  0
< OPCRBH+TeX-mathb10                   Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    373  0
< ITPTFC+CMSS8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    406  0
< BNEURD+stmary10                      Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    412  0
< UQNTKJ+CMMI8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    421  0
< RFERWT+CMMI5                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    444  0
< MBBTWW+TeX-mathb7                    Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    445  0
< GKIQMS+CMSY5                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    446  0
< TURIVV+CMSY8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    451  0
< ORHOJI+CMR6                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    452  0
< QRAQFO+SFTI0800                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes    613  0
< IPQGLW+BBOLD7                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    654  0
< WWCTIW+CMEX7                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    674  0
< JPVWTM+SFIT1000                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes    741  0
< WEZJQK+SFTT0900                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes   1010  0
---
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      22  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      23  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      24  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      25  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      26  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      27  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      30  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      31  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      32  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      33  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      36  0
> XAOMZI+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      37  0
> VSAEDQ+CMMI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      70  0
> DITMCZ+CMSY10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      71  0
> DIERKS+CMR7                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      72  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      74  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      75  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      76  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no      78  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no     113  0
> RQSHZS+CMTT10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     227  0
> DSIQTY+BBOLD10                       Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     230  0
> ULAAHX+CMTI10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     232  0
> OVETDW+CMMI7                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     233  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no     244  0
> CYIPZU+MSAM10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     263  0
> PGWCIV+CMEX10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     265  0
> AWNQRZ+CMSY7                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     266  0
> OYQULM+EUFM10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     267  0
> UWDUBS+CMR5                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     268  0
> ZSIWIM+CMSS10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     269  0
> LUAFXG+rsfs10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     270  0
> HQDOIX+CMMI12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     280  0
> XLUXEV+CMR8                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     281  0
> CHYDRB+MSBM10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     302  0
> SFQIJW+CMSS9                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     304  0
> ECGVGR+CMR9                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     305  0
> BHDBNY+CMMI9                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     306  0
> JIXOQS+CMSY9                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     309  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no     329  0
> OPCRBH+TeX-mathb10                   Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     374  0
> ITPTFC+CMSS8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     407  0
> BNEURD+stmary10                      Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     413  0
> UQNTKJ+CMMI8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     422  0
> RFERWT+CMMI5                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     445  0
> MBBTWW+TeX-mathb7                    Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     446  0
> GKIQMS+CMSY5                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     447  0
> TURIVV+CMSY8                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     452  0
> ORHOJI+CMR6                          Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     453  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no     614  0
> IPQGLW+BBOLD7                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     655  0
> WWCTIW+CMEX7                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     675  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no     742  0
> [none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no    1009  0
```

Perhaps, any intermediate TeX Live version to grab and do the comparison twice: between the old main.pdf and the main.pdf generated by the intermediate TeX Live and then between the main.pdf generated by the intermediate TeX Live and the current main.pdf?

Comment: if you have both texlives available (or you can use overleaf which has a version of every texlive between 2014 -2023) it's much easier to compare the log file to the pdf  (this is the basis of the l3build regression test system) add `\showoutput` and run on each system

Comment: "At least some such warnings on undefined or multiply-defined labels are not completely unexpected." not really, not on any finished document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't have an old texlive readily available. The only thing I easily see is `pdfTeX-1.40.21` for the old version. I could hypothetically decompress the PDF files and look inside if it provides more data on the TeX Live used back then. Concerning *xr-hyper*, perhaps now there warnings for new documents can be avoided, but back in 2019, when the document sources were originally typed in (before the re-compilation in 2022 I mentioned in the question), I recall that the warnings were normal (or at least difficult to avoid without breaking something else).

Comment: as I say you can run the document at overleaf on any texlive back to 2014  pdftex 1.40.21 is texlive  2020 I guess. A bit old...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can't push my stuff to overleaf easily because I have a customized build process via Makefile and several input files. If I were to grab one or two historical TeX Live versions for local installation, which one or which ones should these be: final 2020, final 2021, final 2022, or anything else?

Comment: xr(-hyper) has an impeccable pedigree and wouldn't force warnings, any such must be user error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I saw that xr documentation was last changed by you in 2020. After getting done with comparing the old and new PDF files, I intend to look on those warnings again.

Comment: binaries don't change during a texlive cycle (apart from critical or security updates) so looking at the ones I have 1.40.21 is texlive 2020  no way of knowing  how updated it was when you made the document. get 2020 final I guess

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Will try, thank you! And then use \showoutput and compare the logs?

Comment: probably yes, but latex and contributed packages have many changes if you go back  3 years, visual compatibility is very high but pdf internal structure may change a lot.  If you only have the pdfs you may find just taking bitmap images of each page and doing a bitmap diff allows a comparison without worrying about internals, theer are tools to overlay pages and highlight differences in images

Comment: @DavidCarlisle A bitmap diff in *diffpdf* yields changes everywhere, as antialiasing works now (or works better).

Comment: So my plan now would be to grab final TeX Live 2020, generate the PDF file using it, compare it to what I have, then grab the final TeX Live 2021, generate the PDF file using it, compare it with the one created by the final TeX Live 2021, and so on until I compare the most recent PDF file with the one created by the final TeX Live 2022. Sounds like lots of work, so any improvements to the plan are appreciated …

Comment: That is pretty weird as I'm not aware of any changes in that timeframe that would affect font rendering, unless you are using some non standard font set and the font itself has changes.

Comment: well as I say once you have two texlives I would first compare logs after adding \showoutput   and after normalising the filepaths

Comment: Don't compare the PDFs. Compare the logs. At most you should need to do PDF comparison for the old PDF versus the one now generated with TL 2020. Then you can take the log as the basis for comparison with later TL.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The sources load, among other things, the following font-related packages: fix-cm, comjnl.cls (without options), fontenc, babel, amssymb, mathrsfs, stmaryrd, mathtools, mathbbol, lettrine.

Comment: The first thing I would do is to check the fonts used by the pdfs e.g. with pdffonts or with some pdf reader.

Comment: cm mathrsfs amsfonts stmaryrd have not changed for some decades

Comment: as @UlrikeFischer says try `pdffonts`  if one of your pdfs is using bitmap  type3 fonts instead of type1 it means that version had failed to install the type1 versions of the standard fonts. so not really a change in texlive just a change in installation options.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added some font comparison now. Indeed, I see some Type 3 for the old version.

Comment: @cfr Thank you, I will try!

Comment: that is (almost certainly) a local installation issue not a general texlive one, type1 versions of almost all texlive fonts have been available for years, but they may not be installed in minimal installation options. that would certainly explain antialiasing issues.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Font comparison added, thank you!

Comment: as @DavidCarlisle already suspected: this looks as if you had bitmap fonts in the second (older?) document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I still need to see whether there are any other changed (not related to Type 1). I am installing TeX Live 2020 final now …

Comment: @cfr The old minor version is also 5, so I don't see how changing the minor version would help…

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It turned out that there's already a huge visual difference (due to fonts) between the original old PDF file and the currently produced PDF file using the final TeX Live 2020. I'm going to post a new question on this so as to make new room for comments and answers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  It turned out that there's already a huge visual difference (due to fonts) between the original old PDF file and the currently produced PDF file using the final TeX Live 2020. I'm going to post a new question on this so as to make new room for comments and answers.

Comment: @cfr  It turned out that there's already a huge visual difference (due to fonts) between the original old PDF file and the currently produced PDF file using the final TeX Live 2020. I'm going to post a new question on this so as to make new room for comments and answers.

Comment: Sorry. I misread one of them earlier. If you did a more complete install of TL 2020 than you had when you compiled the original PDF, you'd expect a huge difference. You'd expect that even if TL had been frozen in time simply because you installed a different subset of it this time.